# How to execute a string in document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to execute a string in document ready function? 
This is my string.

```
"if(!$('#frmReportPara').validatec({employee_no_from:{required:true},employee_no_to:{required:true},division_id:{required:true}})){return;}"
```

Comment: eval? But it's not the best solution... may be you should review your goal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a string you need to use one of the functions typically considered `unsafe` like `eval`. Before doing this you should note a few things:

- If someone is able to inject something into your string (say you're saving something in a database) then they could potentially execute code on someone else's browser if they inject malicious code into your database.
- The browser can't optimize this JavaScript due to the `eval` so you'll take some performance hit

So you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myFunc = 'console.log("Foo");'
   eval(myFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   str = "if(!$('#frmReportPara').validatec({employee_no_from:{required:true},employee_no_to:{required:true},division_id:{required:true}})){return;});"
   eval(str);
});
```

Comment: it's not working because your string isn't valid javascript

Comment: @Hashan “not working” is not a problem description. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Also, specify in your question what you have tried. You are expected to show your research!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a eval function:

**code** .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   eval("if(!$('#frmReportPara').validatec({employee_no_from:{required:true},employee_no_to:{required:true},division_id:{required:true}})){return;}"
);
})
```

Be wary though.eval() is considered evil in javascript

Comment: It is not *evil* (or considered evil). It is unsafe if you don’t control the input string.

Comment: Yes it is very easy for a beginner to misuse it which is what i meant.